# Load Data from db, Post it with AJAX to update db, Return back to Load new data! Completely Confused

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

*I want to get my data from mysql db with php and assign them to my javascript array. I have 200 records in my db and i will get 10 records randomly.*

```
$myQuery = mysql_query("select * from tblx where xyz=1 order by rand() limit 10");
```

*What i want to do is take these records to assign them in to an array than show them into my page one by one with fade effect or something else. The user is clicking one of them and its posting the value of this to db than it has to execute a callback function to load new data.

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

```
                              EDIT 2013.06.11
```

## # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #

I'm completely confused so please let the logic clearer.

Here where i get my data from db.

```
index.php


$sorular_hepsi = mysql_query("select * from tblsorular where hafta=1 order by rand() limit 2");
    $soru_ust = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorular_hepsi);
        $soru_id = $soru_ust_rs["id"];
        $soru_grup_id = $soru_ust["sId"];

$soru1 = $soru_ust["soru"];

$sorular = mysql_query("select * from tblsorular where sId=$soru_grup_id");
$totalKayit = mysql_num_rows($sorular_rs);

    while ( $sorular_rs=mysql_fetch_assoc($sorular)) {
        $sorular2[] = $sorular_rs["soru"];
        $sorular2Id[] = $sorular_rs["id"];
    }

$userId = 1234;
```

And here is the listed objects in `index.php`

```
<div id="sorugonder" class="soruStyle">
        <a href="#" class="sorugonder" id="<?=$sorular2Id[0]?>"><?=$sorular2[0]?></a>
    </div>

    <div id="soru_sag" class="soruStyle">
        <a href="#" class="sorugonder2" id="<?=$sorular2Id[1]?>"><?=$sorular2[1]?></a>
    </div>
```

And here is my ajax function to send my data to `islem.php`

```
$(function() {
    $(".sorugonder").click(function() {
    // $('#load').fadeIn();
    var commentContainer = $(this).parent();

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var string = 'id='+ id ;

    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "islem.php?islem=soruKayit",
       data: string,
       cache: false,

       success: function(data){

       commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
             $('#sorugonder').fadeOut(1000);
             $('#soru_sag').fadeOut(2000);

             console.log(string);
             // alert(id);
            }
        });

        return false;

    });
});
```

This function printing console log as `id=xx`

And here is my islem.php page to get ajax data

```
if(isset($_POST["islem"]) && $_POST["islem"]=="soruKayit"){

    header('Content-type: application/json');

    $id= $_POST['string'];
    $cevapTarihi = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");

    $cevapId = json_encode($id);
    $userId = 1234;

     $kayit = @mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblk_skor VALUES(NULL, $userId,$cevapId,$cevapTarihi)");

        if(!$kayit){
                echo "Error:".mysql_error();
        }

    die();

}
```

I've 4 different png pictures and i'm using them as a background for them. For example :

```
$1 = '<img src="../img/1.png" />';
$2 = '<img src="../img/2.png" />';
$3 = '<img src="../img/3.png" />';
$4 = '<img src="../img/4.png" />';
```

I have change my listed datas background on each post process. But i couldn't figure it out how and where i have to put them?

$.ajax function doesn't send my data to islem.php or i can't get it.

Simply :

1. I want to add my record to database (just id )
2. I have to execute callback function to repeat this process 10 times with 10 different records.
3. After finish this 10rec i'm going to calculate the results and redirect to another page.
4. Changing backgrounds every post step.
5. Countdown! I have to put countdown into a div to users click it in 10 seconds. Otherwise i have to execute another error function to start all this again. I couldn't find a proper countdown script to demonstrate on my functions.

Just this.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return your MySql rows as JSON. 
An example:

PHP:

```
<?php
$arr[0]['name']   = 'test0';
$arr[0]['colour'] = 'red';
$arr[1]['name']   = 'test1';
$arr[1]['colour'] = 'blue';
$arr[2]['name']   = 'test2';
$arr[2]['colour'] = 'orange';
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
    echo someThings = json_encode($arr); 
?>
</script>
```

Then further on in your javascript you can do whatever to those values

Javascript:

```
counter = 0;
setInterval(function () {
    if (counter < someThings.length - 1) {
        //do something
    } else {
        counter = 0;
        //do something with the starting element again like 
        alert('The name is ' + someThing[counter].name + ' and the colour is ' + someThing[counter].colour);
    }
    counter++;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: hello @rob You put function in setInterval. Is it refreshing the function in every 5seconds or ? i'm very new in jquery sorry :)

Comment: @LeventKaya Yes the setInterval means that the function will repeat every x milliseconds.  5000 milliseconds = 5 seconds.
If you ever want to stop the interval you can assign the setInterval to a variable like `myInterval = setInterval(function(){....` and then call `clearInterval(myInterval)` when you want to stop the interval.  setTimeout is the same but only runs the given function once.

Answer (score 1):

You should you ajax for this, create an ajax request and send request  to other page the page will fetch data and response back to your page, as AJAX does.

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { XYZ: "1" }
}).done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

here url is the name of page. and type is the type by which you are sending data to that url.
Hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks it is... but what should i do after done() function. i mean after saving my data to db i have to execute another function to repeat this process again. am i gonna write this function to
..
..
}).done(function( msg ) {
    repeatFunctionAgain(); // like this?
  });

Comment: After done show you have all the data, now you can show it on specific div or do what do you want. $('newdata').val(msg);

Comment: what if i don't want to show any message? I mean i want to execute a new query function after its done.. is it possible to call a new function in done() ?

Comment: Yes you can  do this. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can make an ajax call to your page and get the data back(you can json_encode() it), then play around with it, give it fadeIn() effect and so on

Comment: thanks @tinyByte but can you explain me to logic?

Answer (score 0):

A php array can be echoed as JSON using [json_encode](https://www.php.net/json_encode).
So you can create an array of records

```
<?php
//query code here

$results = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($myQuery)){
  $results[] = $row;
}

?>
```

An then in you html you can do:

```
<script>
   var results = <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
<script>
```

and then use this variable in your script as you wish. With little variations you can use the same method with Ajax calls.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I've edited my question. I'm very confused right now and can't figure it out. Its all darkness :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your php value in JSON and conver back to normal with js like below:

**PHP**:

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

PHP Reff: https://www.php.net/json_encode

**Javascript:**

```
var myObject = JSON.parse("my json string");
```

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X6y5B/

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create a variable in php using your query:
The below code is only the demo.I am looping it across an array and creating an array you need to loop it across your while query:

```
<?php
$a="{ ";

for($y=2012;$y<=date("Y")+1;$y++)
{


$a.="'".$y."':{";

for($m=1;$m<=12;$m++)
{
$data_holiday=$ms->holidays($y,$m);
$a.="'".$m."': {";

foreach($data_holiday as $key=>$val)
{
$a.="'".$val['date_day']."': {tooltip: '".$val[Occasion]."', className:'holiday'},";
}

$a.="},";
}


$a.="},";

}

$a.="}";
?>
```

Then you can echo  it in javascript like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var specialDays =<?php echo $a; ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: Hello @vikas I decided to get my datas one by one not as an array. I've changed my question as well. Thank you very much for your help. Maybe you can give some advice for my new edited question.